# Vedic astrology And Lal kitab

Tags: astrology

How different (or similar) is the Vedic astrology from Lal kitab

Which one is preferred over the other and what are the key differences

I have referred the [History of Lal Kitab and its Difference with Vedic Astrology](http://cafejyotish.com/1425-history-of-lal-kitab-and-its-difference-with-vedic-astrology.html) but didn't quite understood it

Comment: Vedic astrology is way more complex, original and accurate dating back to sage Vashishta and Prashara while lal kitab is from the works of Ravana, a brahmrakshasa and devotee of Shiva, hence its tantrik in nature i.e. short, focus on key points and upayas and apt for any Kaliyuga's common person with decreased lifespan and intellect, rather than Vedic detailed study and understanding for scholars.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite different.

In vedic astrology, Ascendant sign is very important. Lal Kitab completely ignores the Ascendant sign and assumes Aries as the ascendant in all cases.

In vedic astrology, predictions are made using the Kundli, Navamsha and various dashas operating at that time. Horoscopes of each individual are separate and independent.
According to Lal Kitab, debts are considered one of the biggest weaknesses of a horoscope. Ancestral Debts means that the person will have effects of the sins done by ancestors and elders. Horoscopes of various members of the family will be related in Lal Kitab.

See
https://ascloud.astrosage.com/cloud/lalkitab-debts-teva.asp

There are several other differences. For a more detailed description, please refer to

Vedic Astrology: An Integrated Approach by P. V.R. Narasimha Rao